# How can i get notification on wifi signal strength change?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-broadcast

Requirement in my application is to show Wifi signal strength on wifi signal change.
For a first time i am calculating the Signal strength by following code.

```
 int numberOfLevels=5;
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        int level=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);
```

I want to update UI frequently if wifi signal is change.
Is there any broadcast available which notify me once signal strength is changed.

Do you any idea How can i achieve this functionality?

Comment: Since Android 8.0 you can't. Targetless broadcasts such as RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION are now disabled, with some exceptions (but RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION is not one of them): https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, yes: the broadcast action is `"android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED"`. See [WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION)

Have never used it personally though.